# Protected/Public Variables Vs. Closures in F#

Tags: f#

Does the following code simulate the difference between protected variables and public variables in F#? Or am I missing something?

```
let (=?) (d:Dictionary<'a,'b>) (x:'a) = d.TryGetValue(x)

let psi (f:'a -> 'b) (d:Dictionary<'a,'b>) = // public dictionary
    let lambda (x:'a) = 
        match (d =? x) with
        | true, i -> i
        | false, _ -> d.Add(x,f x)
                      f x
    lambda

let mem (f:'a -> 'b) = // protected dictionary
    let d = new Dictionary<'a,'b>()
    let orize (input:'a) = 
        match (d =? input) with
        | true, i -> i
        | false, _ -> d.Add(input,f input)
                      f input
    orize
```

Clarification would be excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you actually demonstrate is scope of values in F#.

In the first approach, the dictionary is declared at the module level; therefore, any function in the module can access/modify it. The point is more clear if you drop that second argument in the `psi` function. After each time `psi` invoked, the dictionary is still available and `psi` is a true memoize combinator.

The second approach has dictionary declaration inside a function, and the scope of this dictionary is the function only. Each time you call `mem`, it creates a fresh dictionary so you don't really memorize anything.

In terms of access modifier, your example is closer to `public/private` values. These keywords are [available in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233188.aspx). The `protected` modifier is related to inheritance which you will encounter much less often in F#. And it's another story to tell.

Comment: but isn't that the exact same thing as protected vs public variables?

Those are adjectives that modify scope.  And, according to theory, I must be able to simulate all of C# with F# and vice versa...so if this doesn't illustrate the difference between public and protected, then what does?

Comment: is "module" essentially another word for "let", except this time, every element of the "module" level is public instead of private?

Comment: In terms of access modifier, your example is closer to `public/private` values. These keywords are [available in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233188.aspx). The `protected` keyword is related to inheritance, and it is another story.

Comment: Ah... ok.  now I know what I don't know :)

if I define a class with a protected thing, and inherit it with another thing, I wont inherit the protected stuff...or something like that.  been trying to avoid having to interop with C# every time I want to access protected attributes from the .Net framework.  But I guess that is just an object oriented thing.

thanks pad